# How can I remove the period sign using regex in Python and avoid deleting everything else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, list

```
import regex as re

word_Dict={}#create empty dictionary

with open('poem.txt','r') as f:
    for l in f:
        words=l.split(' ')
        for w in words:
            w = w.strip() #remove \n from all words
            w = re.sub(",", "", w)
            
            #this line is the problem
            w = re.sub(".", "", w)
            #if i comment it everything works okish            

            if w in word_Dict:
                word_Dict[w] += 1
            else:
                word_Dict[w] = 1

    print(word_Dict)
    word_occurances = list(word_Dict.values())
    print(word_occurances)

    for w,w_count in word_Dict.items():
        print(f'The word "{w}" occured {w_count} times.')
```

Hi, So I am trying to find all the different words in a txt file and count the number of times each word is used.

I am trying to remove commas and fullstop or period sign as the program was considering "break" and "break," and "break." as 3 different words.

I used
w = re.sub(",", "", w)
Which works perfectly.

But this line
w = re.sub(".", "", w)
just deletes everything as "." ia asking to delete everything. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: If you just want to remove a single character, you don’t need a regex. If you use a regex, you should learn the basics and what certain special characters mean. http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Questions tend to be clearer when the author begins with a statement of the problem--possibly using one or more examples for illustration--without reference to their unsuccessful attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the problem seems clear enough, OP wants to remove "." and not everything as "." is meant for in regexes. The title is somewhat self-explanatory enough.
OP identified the problem clearly, commenting the line out, it's definitely a valid question.

Comment: @Loïc, the OP wishes to count the number of unique words in a file, which is not evident from the title. Shouldn't the reader be aware of that before wading through the asker's code? I am suggesting how the question can be improved, not that it is without merit.

Comment: Joy, I know little of Python, but I believe you can write `nl = l.strip(" \n.!?")` to remove unwanted bits from the end of the line, then something like `re.split(r"[\s\d.,:;.?!]+", nl)` to gobble up all the unwanted characters between words, but that's still a [dog's breakfast](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20dog%27s%20breakfast#:~:text=British%2C%20informal,is%20messy%20or%20poorly%20done)...

Comment: ...It's easier to keep what you want rather than discard what you don't want. Instead, use `re.findall` for each line: `re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+", l)`. Assuming you want to count "cat" and "Cat" as the same word you need to first convert all letters in the line to the same case, say `ll = l.lower()`, then `re.findall(r"[a-z]+", ll)`. This is not perfect, however. It does not play nice, for example with contractions ("don't") and hyphenated words ("vice-president").

Answer (score 0):

When using regular expressions, some special characters have a special meaning.

In your case, the period "**.**" matches any character except line terminators like "**\n**". That's why this regex removes whole paragraphs.

So you want to do what is called "character escaping", using a backslash to look for the true period sign and not for its special regular expression meaning:

```
re.sub('\.', '', word)
```

From: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

> Regular expressions use the backslash character \ to indicate
> special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
> invoking their special meaning.